# How to get current value of unique identifier,assigned it to global variable and map it in ssis execute SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am using SSIS execute SQL task to execut a stored procedure.In the stored procedure I am passing certain input values and inserting it to a table.This table has got a unique identifier as primary key.As a return output i need the current value of the unique identifier.So I am taking that to a variable @logid as shown below

```
INSERT INTO logging.execution_log
            (ParentLogID,
             Description,
             PackageName,
             PackageGuid,
             MachineName,
             ExecutionGuid,
             LogicalDate,
             Operator,
             StartTime,
             EndTime,
             Status,
             FailureTask)
SELECT @ParentLogID,
       @Description,
       @PackageName,
       Cast(@PackageGuid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),
       @MachineName,
       Cast(@ExecutionGuid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER),
       @logicalDate,
       @operator,
       Getdate(),
       NULL,
       @status,
       NULL

SET @LogID = Cast(Scope_identity() AS INT) ----@logid is output variable from ssis
```

but it is not giving the intended result .Here the assignment of the global variable has been done using **set** operator
to @logid and **mapped** to execute sql ssis task variable.
After some research i found that 
in order to assign the global variables i have to set **SET NOCOUNT** option ON as the first statement in the SQL query .I have done this as well.But it is not returning anything........by the way ****why do we need to set this SET NOCOUNT parameter???**any help welcome**

Comment: Just as a note, unique identifiers in SQL Server are actually their own data type and are different than an INT field that's established as an IDENTITY so it can be confusing to some people if you use the term unique identifier. In SQL Server a `uniqueidentifier` actually looks like: F91D8490-9F68-4366-B577-66CFB8AD7362

Answer (score 1):

In order for a parameter to return the value assigned in the procedure body, the parameter must be declared with the `OUT`/`OUTPUT` keyword in the procedure, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procname (
@logID int OUTPUT,
other parameters
)
AS
body statements
```

*Also*, the corresponding argument in the `EXEC` statement should be supplied with that same keyword (`OUT` or `OUTPUT`), like this:

```
EXEC procname @someGlobalVar OUTPUT, other arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LogID` at the end of your Execute SQL Task and then set your expected result set to single row and configure the result with the single column of LogID and map that to your SSIS global variable.

Let me know if you need me to clarify any of that.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply let me know why do we need set no count on

Comment: Setting NOCOUNT on prevents the server from returning informational messages such as "3 rows affected" whenever you insert, update, or delete records. Often times those informational messages will confuse applications that are expecting output such as  results of a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scope_Identity to get a uniqueidentifier, that is used for Identity column.

To get a uniqueidentifier, you will need to assign it to a variable before using it

```
Set @LogID = NewID()

INSERT INTO logging.execution_log VALUES(...., @logID, ...)
```

Except if you misunderstand what a uniqueidentifier means

Identity columns are auto-generated sequence of integer 1,2,3,4... and works with Scope_Identity.